# Centralize div, without magic numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having a trouble with my html. I have this basic HTML login page:

```
<section>
    <form id="" name="" method="post" action="">
        <label for="username">User:</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" />
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" />
        <input type="submit" id="login" name="login" value="Entrar" />
    </form>
</section>
```

The problem is, how centralize this section, in page, horizontally and vertically, with fixed width, BUT, height auto independent of content?

CSS example:

```
section { width: 300px; }
```

If not possible with CSS only, with jQuery is acepted.

Comment: Check this out http://www.wpdfd.com/editorial/thebox/deadcentre4.html

Comment: No, this example have Magic numbers and define fixed height. Not solve my problem.

Comment: This is possible with CSS alone: http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using jQuery you could do this by

1. getting the height of the window
2. subtracting the height of the `section` element you want to center.
3. divide that value in half.
4. make the margin-top of the `section` element to that final number.

Like this:

```
var ht = $(window).height();
var sectionHt = $('section').height();
var pad = (ht - sectionHt)/2;

$('section').css('margin-top',pad);
```

As an example: http://jsfiddle.net/JMC_Creative/8RpQZ/

---

Or, if you want it to stay centered when the window is resized, you do the same thing, but wrap it in the `$(window).resize()` jQuery method. like this:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    var ht = $(window).height();
    var sectionHt = $('section').height();
    var pad = (ht - sectionHt)/2;

    $('section').css('margin-top',pad);
});
```

Comment: It's quite pathetic that we have to resort to scripting languages (which may be disabled in many browsers - or simply not supported) for some things that should just "work out of the box".

Comment: @Giovani, maybe so, but it *doesn't* work out of the box. It just doesn't. And javascript is pretty standard and works in most browsers at this point in the history of the world.

Comment: Jake, tks for your answer. If there was a solution in pure CSS, would be nice, but if does not exist, it would help me even. How I set to, when zoom in browser is used, the script start again?

Comment: .resize() works, or at least window resize event does it. http://api.jquery.com/resize/ It works with zooming or resizing window, if I recall.

Comment: @JakeParis yep. I agree. JavaScript is great. It just seems like they didn't give much thought to design when they originally wrote the specs for html/css.

Comment: Great Jake. Tks for the answer man. You save my day! =]. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

```
<section>
    <form id="" name="" method="post" action="">
        <label for="username">User:</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" />
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" />
        <input type="submit" id="login" name="login" value="Entrar" />
    </form>
</section>

section {
    width: 300px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 250px; /* pixels from top of page - if you have the height to be auto, may see different changes, however, this could be what you want if you want the form to be in the exact center -- simply change the px's to suit your needs */
}
```

Is this what you are asking?  Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zyFG5/

**EDIT:**

Ok, give this a shot:

```
<section>
    <form id="" name="" method="post" action="">
        <label for="username">User:</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" />
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" />
        <input type="submit" id="login" name="login" value="Entrar" />
    </form>
</section>

section {
   width: 300px;
   height: 300px;
   position: absolute;
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%; 
   margin-left: -150px;
   margin-top: -150px;
}
```

Negative margins are exactly half the height and width, which pull the element back into perfect center. Only works with elements of a fixed height/width.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DDZmY/

Comment: Tks for your response. But not solve my problem. My div has a dinamic heigth, and I can't fix a value of top. I need something to do automatically. And your answer, try to zoom in, and see that as the top is fixed, it will not be in the center of the screen if I give the page zoom.

Comment: Made an Edit - Is that what you are asking for?

Answer (score 0):

A bit of css can help you achieve what you are after. Though it may take some tweaking to get what you want exactly.

Set your section to relative position so you can align it vertically. Then set an auto left/right margin so it is centered horizontally...

```
section{position:relative;top:200px;
  margin:auto;
  width:300px;
  border:2px outset #0af;
  text-align:right;
  background-color:#fff;
  padding:6px;
}
```

another way is a bit hacky, but seems to work ok. You create a div with height 100% (and which would be invisible) and vertically align your section to this.

Here's something you can fork... http://codepen.io/lukeocom/pen/Dmdnh

Comment: Not working, in my browser, the form is stuck to bottom of page.

Comment: Tks man, but your answer, don't solve my problem. The top is fixed.

Comment: may be browser dependant. Check the updated codepen. Resize the main container to see what happens. The resize handle wont work in IE. prob not what your after, but interesting nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery:

```
$(function(){
    var height = $(window).height();
    var width = $(window).width();

    var blockHeight = $(".block").height();
    var blockWidth = $(".block").width();

    var paddingTop = (height/2 - blockHeight);
    var paddingWidth = (width/2 - blockWidth);

    $(".block").css({
        'padding-top':paddingTop,
        'padding-left':paddingWidth
     });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zyFG5/2/